# Setting Creamy color as my back ground

Tags: java, user-interface, colors, rgb

I want to set a creamy color as my background but this is what it says when I tried a Color.Creamy constant:

```
 cannot find symbol symbol  : variable Creamy location: class
 java.awt.Color label.setBackground(Color.Creamy);
                          ^ 1 error
```

So I am wondering how I could create and use a cream color in Java?

Comment: Creamy is not a default color, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html for more information. You will need to make your own color

Comment: you will have to make your own

Comment: Color.TheShadeOfOrangeOnTheTopBarOfTheStackOverflowLogo ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no color Creamy in Java: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html

Answer (score 1):

That is because there is not a static color defined in java.awt.Color called Creamy.

```
label.setBackground(new Color(255, 255 204));
```

Should do what you want it to do using the color on this page http://www.colorcombos.com/colors/FFFFCC

The number of colors in java.awt.Color is very limited. Make your own using "new Color(r,g,b)" to get a wide variety of Colors. If you don't know the rgb values for a color, google "*Colorname* rgb" and one of the first few results should have the values to plug in.

Comment: setBackground() method is for a drawable, must use setBackgroundColor() method.

Answer (score 0):

There are no "creamy color" the constants defined by the android.graphics.Color Class are:

```
**Constants** 

int BLACK  
int BLUE  
int CYAN  
int DKGRAY  
int GRAY  
int GREEN  
int LTGRAY  
int MAGENTA  
int RED  
int TRANSPARENT  
int WHITE  
int YELLOW
```

You can look for your "creamy color" for example:
http://www.colorpicker.com/F7F3C3

and you have several choices to set your color with:

```
.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F7F3C3"));
```

or

```
.setBackgroundColor(0xF7F3C3);
```

or you can define your "creamy color" into the [colors.xml](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Color) file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>     
    <color name="creamy">#F7F3C3</color> 
...
...
```

and using:

```
.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.creamy));
```